# Save dropdown list value to SQL Database Entry

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm doing an exercise for university where I have created a `SQL Database` and linked it to a grid view in Visual Studio with help of Entity Framework. To create a new entry on the database I have to fill some text fields (e.g: Name, Stock).

Now, I know that from a text field, depending on it being `string`, `decimal` or `integer`, I use the following to bind each text field to the respective section on the table in the database and therefore save its value(.cs code):

```
Rugby entry = new Rugby();
entry.Stock = int.Parse(txtStock.Text);
entry.Name = txtName.Text;
```

If I want to add a `dropdown` list to my code and from there take one of the values available and save it to new entry being created in the given table (Category), how would I complete the following bit line of code:

```
entry.Category=???(bit that I don't know how to complete)
```

Comment: Have you already brought your EF diagrams into VS?

Comment: Yes, I have the Model.edmx file which I think is what you mean @confusedandamused

Comment: There is no such thing as a **SQL database** - SQL is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems, but it's not a database product. Many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know **what database system** (and which version) you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Comment: @marc_s Does Entity Framework support other query languages (Aside from the MS flavor)?  I wasn't aware that it did.

Comment: @confusedandamused Entity Framework operates with any [ADO.NET Data Provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6cd7c08(v=vs.110).aspx) which provides an interface to plug in data backends. (e.g [Npgsql](http://www.npgsql.org/))

Comment: @ChanceSnow That you for the clarification :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already brought in your EF Diagrams into Visual Studio (to your .edmx files), and I am understanding your table structures correctly you can simply do it like this:

```
 // This will be what you named your entities from your .edmx
 // This object sets up the connection to your entities 
 public static myEntities _db = new myEntities ();

(Auto-Generated Class via .edmx)
// When you add an .edmx file (database diagram for EF)
// There is an auto-generated class you are able to use - 
// We are setting this up below.
EF_Class_Name newDbEntry= new EF_Class_Name();


// You can access any property of the class just like any other object
// property.
newDbEntry.Stock = int.Parse(txtStock.Text);
newDbEntry.Name = txtName.Text;
newDbEntry.Category = dropdown.SelectedValue;


// Add your new data (essentially an insert)
_db.EF_Class_Name.Add(newDbEntry);

// Commit the changes
_db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Even though I'm pretty confused with what is going on in the comments this worked. Thanks!

Comment: @JGuerra Is there anything I can add to my answer to help understanding?  I'll add a bit now to maybe clear some stuff up.

Comment: thanks for the update, it did help to understand it better. Apologies for the late reply. Worked a treat!

Answer (score 0):

Your `Rugby` entity should also have FK property (`CategoryId`), this way you are able to save the `SelectedValue` of your dropdown list to establish the relationship:

```
entry.CategoryId=dropdown.SelectedValue;
```

This is assuming you are setting your dropdown list like this way:

```
var categories = (from c in context.Categories
                            select new { c.CategoryId, c.CategoryName }).ToList();

// Change this for the real property names
dropdown.DataValueField = "CategoryId";
dropdown.DataTextField = "CategoryName";
dropdown.DataSource = categories;
dropdown.DataBind();
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but how would you set the FK property? @octavioccl

Comment: @JGuerra This is something you setup in MSSQL Server, and then update your diagrams to bring it in.